# spark how to reduce by column of data type is date

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I am working on a DataFrame looks as follows:

```
-------------------------------
| time                | value | 
-------------------------------
| 2014-12-01 02:54:00 |    2  |
| 2014-12-01 03:54:00 |    3  |
| 2014-12-01 04:54:00 |    4  |
| 2014-12-01 05:54:00 |    5  |
| 2014-12-02 02:54:00 |    6  |
| 2014-12-02 02:54:00 |    7  |
| 2014-12-03 02:54:00 |    8  |
-------------------------------
```

the number of samples on each day is pretty random.

I want to get just one sample on each day, such as:

```
-------------------------------
| time                | value | 
-------------------------------
| 2014-12-01 02:54:00 |    2  |
| 2014-12-02 02:54:00 |    6  |
| 2014-12-03 02:54:00 |    8  |
-------------------------------
```

I don't care about which sample I get from one day, but
I want to make sure to get one so there is no day duplication
on "time" column.

Comment: which programming language are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a date column first and then `dropDuplicates` based on the `date` column; Example with `pyspark`, the syntax should be similar if you are using `scala` or `java`:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df.withColumn('date', f.to_date('time', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) \
  .dropDuplicates(['date']).drop('date').show()
+-------------------+-----+
|               time|value|
+-------------------+-----+
|2014-12-02 02:54:00|    6|
|2014-12-03 02:54:00|    8|
|2014-12-01 02:54:00|    2|
+-------------------+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions, generate row_number by partitioning on date value and filter on row_number=1

Check this out:

```
val df = Seq(("2014-12-01 02:54:00","2"),("2014-12-01 03:54:00","3"),("2014-12-01 04:54:00","4"),("2014-12-01 05:54:00","5"),("2014-12-02 02:54:00","6"),("2014-12-02 02:54:00","7"),("2014-12-03 02:54:00","8"))
  .toDF("time","value")
df.withColumn("time",'time.cast("timestamp")).withColumn("value",'value.cast("int"))
df.createOrReplaceTempView("timetab")
spark.sql(
  """ with order_ts( select time, value , row_number() over(partition by date_format(time,"yyyyMMdd") order by value ) as rn from timetab)
    select time,value from order_ts where rn=1
  """).show(false)
```

Output:

```
+-------------------+-----+
|time               |value|
+-------------------+-----+
|2014-12-02 02:54:00|6    |
|2014-12-01 02:54:00|2    |
|2014-12-03 02:54:00|8    |
+-------------------+-----+
```